# .NET Core EF searching on many fields

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table with many text fields. On the UI side I just want to make a google like search where there is just 1 textbox and I'll take what they enter there and look into doing a FREETEXT search on the various text fields via linq. My question would be what's the best way to do this? Would I run the same query as many times as fields I want to search on each one doing the search on that one specific field and then join all the results then distinct on that or is there a more efficient way to do this?

So if a user types "Business" there could be 5 different fields in my table that I want the FreeText search to be done on.

Comment: How many rows in the table, how many concurrent requests expected, any clue on how many distinct words available for searching?

Comment: Right now there are 0 rows as it's being developed but I'd say maybe 500 rows a year. This is all internal to a small shop so maybe 2 or 3 concurrent requests and pretty infrequently. The user searching could type anything in as the users can type anything in the fields on creation of the record.

Comment: If it is that "small" saying only 500 rows pr year i would start by doing one linq/sql with a `.Contains(x)` on each field - for a start. So one shot which filters on all 5 fields at the same time.

Comment: i forgot to ask how big/long -estimated- are each of those 5 fields?

Comment: You can easily test it. Create the 500 rows and stuff them with lorem ipsum as long you expect them to be - and do some searching on those.

Comment: I would go with Frank's suggestion using ```.Contains(x)``` or ```.Any(x => x.... == ...)```. Additionally a good practice is to add the test data generation to migration. So the test can be run in multiple environments like dev and qa. I would suggests Bogus nuget to generate any kind of test data.

Comment: @FrankNielsen So just OR .Contains() on each column I'm interested in in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple field query like:

```
 var textFilter = "hi";
 dbSet.Where( s => s.Field1.Constains(textFilter) ||
                   s.Field2.Constains(textFilter) ||
                   s.Field3.Constains(textFilter) ||
                   s.Field4.Constains(textFilter) ||
                   s.Field5.Constains(textFilter) ).ToListAsync();
```

and see how that performance over 500 ~ 1000 rows.